# Replace specific character within a pattern

Tags: regex, sed

I am looking for a way to delete specific characters from within a string matching a regex pattern. I stored text with linebreaks in a tab-separated file supposed to have one record per line and I'm trying to replace all line breaks with spaces. Linebreaks do not occur in the last colum (which is a short column with an alphanumeric key).

The way to solve it IMHO is to replace every instance of `\n` within the following pattern:

```
[^\t]*\t[^\t]*
```

My solution until now uses three steps:

1. replace the "good" `\n` with a special string absent from the rest of the text (e.g. long number) using `s/\([^\t]*\t{x}[^\t]*\)\n/\1#12398754987235649876234#/g` with `x` being one less than the intended number of columns in my files
2. replace all the ("bad") `\n` with a space
3. replace the long number with a new line

But I have quite a few gigabytes of text files and I'm looking for a way to do this in a **single** `sed` **step**.

Example input:

```
foo \t Each multiplex has screens allocated \n
to each studio. \t abc \n
bar \t The screens need filling. \t bcd \n
123 \t Studios have to create product to fill \n
their screen, and the amount of good product is limited. \t cde \n
```

Output:

```
foo \t Each multiplex has screens allocated to each studio. \t abc \n
bar \t The screens need filling. \t bcd \n
123 \t Studios have to create product to fill their screen, and the amount of good product is limited. \t cde \n
```

Comment: Do lines literally start with a number?

Comment: No. I modified my example to remove the ambiguity. There is NO pattern in the columns (can be text, numbers, punctuation...), except for the `\t` which is only used to separate columns.

Comment: You are trying to remove any `\n` that does *not* follow ". ", is that right?

Comment: No, as I wrote above, the content does not follow any pattern, except that there are no `\t` inside.

Comment: Then I can't make sense of your example. Between two tabs you remove one line break, but not another.

Comment: @Beta: you are right, I realize there is something wrong with my example again: the last column does not include linebreaks. I modified my example to show this.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
cat file
foo     Each multiplex has screens allocated
to each studio.
bar     The screens need filling.
123     Studios have to create product to fill
their screen, and the amount of good product is limited.
```

If a line does contain tab `\t` then connect it to the next line.

```
awk 'NR>1 {s=/\t/?"\n":" "}{printf s"%s",$0} END {print ""}'
foo     Each multiplex has screens allocated to each studio.
bar     The screens need filling.
123     Studios have to create product to fill their screen, and the amount of good product is limited.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;$!N;s/\n([^\t]+)$/\1/;ta;P;D' file
```

Read 2 lines into the pattern space (PS) and if the last line doesn't contain a tab, remove the newline and read in the next line and repeat.
If the line does contain a tab, print the first line and then delete it and then repeat.

Answer (score 0):

It's always tricky to handle previous lines with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed), because of its limitations of small number of buffers, non-greedy quantifiers, lack of look-ahead, and much more, but here you have an approach. It's commented but I know it's not easy to follow

```
sed -n '
    ## Label "a"
    :a;
    ## Enter this section after join all lines without a tab.
    /\t.*\t/ {
        ## Loop to remove all newlines but the last one, because it is
        ## next line with a tab that I dont want to print now.
        :b;
        /\n[^\n]*\n/ { 
            s/\n/ /; 
            bb 
        }; 
        ## Print until newline (all joined lines) and delete them
        P; 
        D;
    };
    ## Append next line to buffer and repeat loop.
    N; 
    $! ba;
    ## Special case for last line, remove extra newlines and print. 
    s/\n/ /g; 
    p
' infile
```

Assuming `infile` with following content:

```
foo     Each multiplex has screens allocated
to each studio.
bar     The screens need filling.
123     Studios have to create product to fill
their screen, and the amount of good product is limited.
```

It yields:

```
foo     Each multiplex has screens allocated to each studio.
bar     The screens need filling.
123     Studios have to create product to fill their screen, and the amount of good product is limited.
```